# Highcharts JSON, chart not displaying

Tags: javascript, php, json, highcharts, temperature

I have some data I wish to display on a chart but it just shows the title and no points get drawn. The JSON data I receive is correct as per my knowledge, I think it's somewhere in the chart function but I can't really point it out.

This is what I have so far:
data.php (the output):

```
{"name":"Temperature","data":[34,28,29,28,34,28,32,27,24,30,25,32,34,28,34,33,24,33,30,27,24,27,26,29]}
```

The important bits of the html:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature vs. Time',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['12AM', '1AM', '2AM', '3AM', '4AM', '5AM', '6AM', '7AM', '8AM', '9AM', '10AM', '11AM','12PM', '1PM', '2PM', '3PM', '4PM', '5PM', '6PM', '7PM', '8PM', '9PM', '10PM', '11PM']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                series: json
            });
        });
    });    
});
</script>
```

It's supposed to show temperature per hour but unfortunately nothing comes up. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: it might be useful to make a demo on codepen.io or something like that in this case, so people could mangle with your code quickly and figure what's the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`series` should be an array. So you need to just change:

`series: json`

To:

`series: [json]`

Working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Kfgsd

Documentation: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Answer (score 0):

your problem i think that you haven't specified where your chart should be inserted to, afaik you either should specify the `renderTo` option for the class constructor options or use the `$('#container').haighcharts({...})` jquery helper

Comment: I have `renderTo: 'container'` in the function and another div linked to it in the html as follows: `<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>`

Comment: doh, sorry, you're right. i thought you said that it doesn't render anything at all